# How to deal with `app_engine_apis` warning when updating app.yaml from go114 to go115

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I recently updated my `app.yaml` from

```yaml
runtime: go114
```

to

```yaml
runtime: go115
```

because I was warned in an email that support for `go114` was ending.

The service deployed fine but after it finished, I got the message:

> Updating service [default]...⠼WARNING: There is an indirect dependency on App Engine APIs, but they are not enabled in your app.yaml. You may see runtime errors trying to access these APIs. Set the app_engine_apis property.

So I added:

```yaml
app_engine_apis: true
```

And now the service won't deploy and gives this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [<snip>/app.yaml]
> Unexpected attribute 'app_engine_apis' for object of type AppInfoExternal.

Looks like a catch 22. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Do you have a dependency on the GAE SDK at google.golang.org/appengine?

Comment: More specifically, looks like this is triggered: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/94e880b8487422bb3e1e8367f75373cb9f2dc110/cmd/go/appengine/main.go#L60. Since those APIs aren't enabled yet in go115, you might get a runtime error.

Comment: I see. Turns out the import was in dead code using old versions of GCP packages. The warning disappeared after it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as community wiki as it's based on @Joel's comments.

It looks like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/94e880b8487422bb3e1e8367f75373cb9f2dc110/cmd/go/appengine/main.go#L60) is being triggered, since those APIs aren't enabled yet in `go115`, you might get a runtime error.

I would say that you should probably reach out to Google Cloud either in their [Issue Tracker system](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) or open an Issue in this [Github Page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues) so that they can fix this issue, as there doesn't seem to be any workarounds for this one.

Comment: It seems like the go115 runtime now (November 2021) supports bundled services, albeit only when using "gcloud beta app deploy" since it's in a pre-GA state: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/services/access. Without "beta", deploying prints "WARNING: There is a dependency on App Engine APIs, but they are not enabled in your app.yaml. Set the app_engine_apis property." even if the property is present.