# Unexpected attribute app_engine_apis error deploying Python 3 App Engine Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I use Google App Engine standard environemment with Flask Python3 for a current project.
This project use as cache the App Engine Memcache (google.appengine.api.memcache).

Currently the cache doesn't work and I think that it's probably because of the dependency on App Engine APIs that need to be enable because when I try to deploy my app (gcloud app deploy) I have this warning: `WARNING: There is a dependency on App Engine APIs, but they are not enabled in your app.yaml. Set the app_engine_apis property.`

My issue is that when I try to set the dependancy in my app.yaml and deploy, I have then this error: `Unexpected attribute 'app_engine_apis' for object of type AppInfoExternal.`

I also tried with the exact same yaml file than the Google example: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine/blob/master/mod12b-memcache/app.yaml, it doesn't work.

Here the current app.yaml that I'm trying to use:

```
runtime: python39
env: standard
app_engine_apis: true

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 15

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
```

This issue is almost the same as this question but I couldn't use it to solve my problem: [How to deal with `app_engine_apis` warning when updating app.yaml from go114 to go115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893661/how-to-deal-with-app-engine-apis-warning-when-updating-app-yaml-from-go114-to)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are using GAE Flex.  `app_engine_apis: true` might be only for GAE Standard.

Comment: New name is correct: you can only use bundled services in GAE Std. Remove the `env: standard` in your `app.yaml` file. Also, what's in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Furthermore, show us how your app is using the WSGI wrapper that you imported at the top of your main application file with `from google.appengine.api import wrap_wsgi_app`. Also NoCommandLine may be correct below if you have an older version of the Cloud SDK installed. Run `gcloud components update` if you don't want to issue `beta` with `gcloud app deploy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) is outdated. Per the comments in [@NoCommandLine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15211203/nocommandline)'s answer, your SDK being version 300 is from Jul 2020 whereas the bundled services for 2nd-gen runtimes like Python 3 didn't go into private preview until Jun 2021. They became [generally available in Sep 2021](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/support-for-app-engine-services-in-second-generation-runtimes). If you run `gcloud components update` to get the latest SDK (at the time of this post, it's 410), you should be able to run `gcloud app deploy` to deploy a Python 3 App Engine app that can access the [Memcache bundled service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/memcache). **TL;DR** To use bundled services in Python 3:

1. Add `app_engine_apis: true` to `app.yaml`
2. Add `appengine-python-standard` to `requirements.txt`
3. Import the WSGI wrapper: `from google.appengine.api import wrap_wsgi_app`
4. Wrap your WSGI object (Flask): `app = Flask(__name__); app.wsgi_app = wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app)`
5. Review [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access#installing), esp. if you're *not* using Flask
6. **Update your Cloud SDK**: `gcloud components update`

> NOTE: You no longer need to run `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` to vendor/self-bundle package dependencies... they're now automatically installed for Py3 users (but not Py2 though) when you deploy your app to the cloud.

I [recently published a video & codelab (hands-on tutorial) on how to access the bundled services from "Gen2"](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/10/extending-support-for-app-engine-bundled-services-module-17.html?utm_source=bl%20og&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=CDR_wes_aap-serverless_mgrwormhole_sms_202002) but realize now I should've mentioned updating your SDK, meaning it covers *almost* all of the instructions above. `:P`

For those interested in eventually migrating off Memcache to something more powerful like Redis, I also [published content on migrating from Memcache to Cloud Memorystore for Redis](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/06/Migrating-from-App-Engine-Memcache-to-Cloud-Memorystore-Module-13.html?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=CDR_wes_aap-serverless_mgrmemorystore_sms_202029), relatively recently as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of gcloud probably means the app_engine_apis are in the beta version and so you have to do

`gcloud beta app deploy`

Comment: Hello NoCommandLine,

Thanks for your answer but I tried both `gcloud app deploy` and `gcloud beta app deploy` and the same error occurs :/

gcloud version:

gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 300.0.0
app-engine-go
app-engine-python 1.9.91
beta 2020.07.06
bq 2.0.58
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2020.07.06
gsutil 4.51

Comment: Bundled Services for Python 3 was announced sometime in September 2021. According to the release notes (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes), the earliest Google Cloud SDK version in Sep 2021 was 356.0.0. You say you're on 300.0.0. Upgrade your SDK and try again. If you upgrade to the latest version, you won't have to use beta. Just use ```gcloud app deploy```